# How do I connect my python spyder with github? i want to create/update/delete python files on github using spyder environment

Tags: python, git, github, spyder

how can i integrate spyder and Github?
I've done the python code in google collab then transferred to spyder environment and make it working there, then i moved this python code (.py) file to github.
Is there anyway to connect Github and spyder, we can browse and open Github files in spyder and create/update it.